# BeforeEach hook error: Variable implicitly has type any. Hardhat, solidity contract tests

Tags: typescript, testing, hook, solidity, hardhat

I do testing of smart contract (Solidity, Hardhat) on TS. When I made hook beforeEach I've gotten an error: Variable implicitly has type any...
Inside ït..." everything works good.
What did I miss?
thank you

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

describe("MyToken", function () {
 let Token;
 let newToken;
 let owner;
 let addr2;
 let addr3;
 let addrs;


 beforeEach(async function () {
Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
[owner, addr2, addr3, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners();
newToken = await Token.deploy("MyToken", "MTK", 1000, 100);
await newToken.deployed();
});

it("Should return name from getter getName", async function () {

expect(await newToken.name()).to.equal("MyToken");
});
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the type of `newToken`

Comment: How to do this in my case? thank you

Comment: You can just declare it as `let newToken: any;`

Answer (score 0):

Install [typechain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typechain), every time your contracts compile the types will be generated for them. They can be then used in test cases and deployment scripts.

```bash
npm install --save-dev typechain
```

Add the following to your hardhat config:

```json
  typechain: {
    outDir: "<contracts-directory>/types",
    target: "ethers-v5",
  },
```

Once your contracts have been compiled, you can define the type:

```js
// Import type
import { MyToken, MyToken__factory } from "../../<contracts-directory>/types";
...
// Declare variable with type
let Token: MyToken__Factory;
let newToken: MyToken;
...
// Usage
Token = (await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")) as MyToken__Factory;
...
newToken = (await Token.deploy("MyToken", "MTK", 1000, 100)) as MyToken;
```

**Note:** Please avoid `any`, defeats the whole purpose of TS